# I want to check if user is online in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Goal

> I want to display a message based on whether the user is online or offline.

---

### Summary of the Problem

- **Error:**
  Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
- Problem is mainly caused by a `setInterval()` which calls a function every 6 second that changes the state (created using `useState` hook)

---

### Expected Result:

A function is called with a set interval that checks whether a user is online or offline and then displays a message if a user is offline

---

### What I have tried:

```js
export default function CardContainer() {
 const [isOnline, set_isOnline] = useState(true);
 function InternetErrMessagenger() {
    if (navigator.onLine===true) set_isOnline(true);
    if (navigator.onLine===false) set_isOnline(false);
 }
 setInterval(InternetErrMessagenger(), 6000);
 return (
    // the <InternetChecker /> component contains a message that gets displayed when offline
    {isOnline !== true ? <InternetChecker /> : ""}
 )
```

---

### A Glimpse of my effort:

[image]

> NOTE: I was thinking of using the `useEffect` hook to solve this problem but could not make out how to do so. If you are thinking of any other way of addressing this problem, please share with me.

Comment: Socket IO is the best way to develop chat and user online app.
https://socket.io/

Comment: @GautamParmar The OP wants to check the network status.

Comment: Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine

Comment: `import useOnlineStatus from '@rehooks/online-status';`, then inside your component: `const isOnline = useOnlineStatus();`

Comment: Thank you, [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/paul). This is the easiest way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this

1. **`useEffect`** will initiate the setInterval on component mount return function of the useEffect remove the interval event after comopnent unmount

**[Codesanbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dan-l1yrp)**

```
export default function CardContainer() {
 const [isOnline, set_isOnline] = useState(true);
 let interval = null;

 const InternetErrMessagenger = () => set_isOnline(navigator.onLine===true); // for do like this shortform

 
 useEffect(()=>{
    interval = setInterval(InternetErrMessagenger, 6000); // call the function name only not with function with call `()`
    return ()=>{
       clearInterval(interval) // for component unmount stop the interval
    }
 },[])
 
 return (
    // the <InternetChecker /> component contains a message that gets displayed when offline
    {isOnline !== true ? <InternetChecker /> : ""}
 )
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done.

Comment: I am using the chrome dev tools to virtually set 'online' and 'offline'. When I am setting it to  'offline', the component is not getting rendered.

Comment: @DronBhattacharya try now. setInterval function call was wrong now updated. its working https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dan-l1yrp

Comment: The code is not working when I am opening it in a new tab

Comment: chrome dev offline mode  working on same window not affect the all the window. better turn off your wifi or LAN and try

Comment: Outer scope values like 'navigator.onLine' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: @Desmond yes Thanks, i forgot. you are right .its does not make any sense. I just wrapped with normal function

Answer (score 1):

Solved it on codesandbox using `window.addEventListener('online')` and `window.addEventListener('offline')`

https://codesandbox.io/s/check-online-status-xdnos
check out

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet code.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('online', function(e) {
        console.log('And we\'re back :).');
    }, false);
                
    window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) {
        console.log('Connection is down.');
    }, false);
},[])
```